# Не работает функция, вычисляющая определитель матрицы

Tags: математика, pascal, матрицы, freepascal

Здравствуйте. Кто любит решать головоломки? Мне не нужна готовая функция вычисляющая определитель. Мне нужно знать почему не работает моя? Для n = 2, ясное дело, работает; но для 3-х уже даёт неверный результат.

```
function det(A: Matrix): integer;
var
    M: Matrix;
    n, i, sum, t: integer;
begin
    n := Length(A);
    if n = 2 then begin
        det := A[0][0]*A[1][1] - A[0][1]*A[1][0];
        exit;
    end;
    sum := 0;
    for i := 0 to n-1 do begin
        M := minor(A, i, 0);
        sum := sum + Trunc(Power(-1, i+2)) * A[0][i] * det(M);
    end;
    det := sum;
end;
```

Функция minor (с ней должно быть всё в порядке):

```
function minor(A: Matrix; x, y: integer): Matrix;
var
    t: Matrix;
    n, i, j, tx, ty: integer;
begin
    n := Length(A);
    SetLength(t, n-1, n-1);
    for i := 0 to n-1 do
        for j := 0 to n-1 do begin
            if i = y then break;
            if j = x then continue;
            tx := j; ty := i;
            if i > y then ty := ty - 1;
            if j > x then tx := tx - 1;
            t[ty][tx] := A[i][j];
        end;
    minor := t;
end;
```

Если что:

```
type Matrix = array of array of integer
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `Trunc(Power(-1, i+2))`?

Comment: Тут всё норм. Хотя можно записать и проще: Trunc(Power(-1, i)). Сделать это ещё проще не представляю себе возможным.

Comment: Например, `Odd(i) ? -1 : 1`. Или если в Паскале нету тернарного оператора, то через `if`. Функция `Power` — не самая быстрая.

---
Гугл подсказывает: `IfThen(Odd(i), -1, 1)`.

Comment: @VladD: Был бы тут Си, я б показал, как такие вещи делают  н а с т о я щ и е   у м е л ь ц ы .

Comment: @IncnisMrsi: Бинарные трюки или улучшение алгоритма?

Comment: @VladD: Замена условного выполнения на битовые операции. Думаю, Вы поняли.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi: Кстати, с хорошей долей вероятности, gcc делает эту оптимизацию сам на -O3.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi: Обычный трюк состоит в том, чтобы завести переменную, присвоить вначале 1 и менять знак на каждой итерации. Не скажу без тестирования, что быстрее: это или битовые операции.

Answer (score 1):

Всё очень просто: переполнение! Нужно заменить integer на Int64. После Pyhton'a вообще об этом забыл...